# Identificar inputs em uma div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Gente eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de identificar inputs dentro de uma div, sem usar nome, id ou class.

Exemplo:

```
<div>

      <input type='text'>

      <input type='text'>

      <input type='text>

     <button onclick='enviar(enviar-o-texto-do-primeiro-input, enviar-o-texto-do-segundo-input , enviar-o-texto-do-terceiro-input);>enviar</button>

</div>
```

Eu queria poder enviar os texto dos input sem usar id, class, nome, pois estou criando as div automaticamente e se botar um id para cada um, todas as outras div vão ter o mesmo id nos input.

Answer (score 2):

Pode pegar pelo nome da tag usando `.getElementsByTagName()` com os índices dos elementos, começando do `0`. Mas antes é preciso pegar a div pai com `.parentNode`.

Para isso, basta enviar à função o próprio botão com `this`:

```js
function enviar(botao){
   var text_1 = botao.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
   var text_2 = botao.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value;
   var text_3 = botao.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("input")[2].value;
   console.log(text_1, text_2, text_3);
}
```

```html
<div>
   <input type='text' value="A">
   <input type='text' value="B">
   <input type='text' value="C">
   <button onclick='enviar(this)'>enviar</button>
</div>
```

No caso de não ter um número definido de inputs, uma outra abordagem seria contar quantos intputs a div contém e adicionar os textos numa array:

```js
function enviar(b){
   
   var textos = [];
   var bts = b.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("input");
   for(var botao of bts){
      textos.push(botao.value);
   }
   
   console.log(textos);
   
}
```

```html
<div>
   <input type='text' value="A">
   <input type='text' value="B">
   <input type='text' value="C">
   <button onclick='enviar(this)'>enviar</button>
</div>
```

Você terá uma array com os textos e poderá usá-los como quiser.

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu consegui fazer do jeito que vc falou. existe aqui algum canto de botar a pergunta como resolvida ou de marca a sua como melhor resposta?

Comment: Tem à esquerda, abaixo das setas de votação.